# How to get userInfo JSON Value inside didReceiveRemoteNotification in swift4?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, push-notification

How to get userInfo JSON Value inside didReceiveRemoteNotification in swift? json is written below i need it in my didReceiveRemoteNotification method. Any pointers how to do that is appreciated

```
              ["aps": {
  alert = "Manohar Nikam liked your review";
  "content-available" = 1;
  sound =
  default;
 }, "u": {
  "receiver_id": 3,
  "type": "like",
  "review_id": 177,
  "sender_id": 23,
  "like_count": 1,
  "helpful_count": 0,
  "profile_pic": "https://ace-dev-2019.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profile/RemoteConfigImageIOS.png",
  "restaurant_id": 4,
  "restaurant_thumbnail": "https://ace-dev-2019.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/restaurant_images/ThePeshwaPavilionITCMaratha_thumbnail.png",
  "title": "Manohar Nikam liked your review"
 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply implement **`application(_: didReceiveRemoteNotification:)`** method in `AppDelegate` and use `userInfo` to fetch the `aps` and other data from it.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String:Any] {
        //use aps dictionary here...
    }
    if let u = userInfo["u"] as? [String:Any] {
        //use u dictionary here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root level item of the `userInfo` dictionary is "aps", not "alert".

Try the following:

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
           //Do stuff
        }
    } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

See [Push Notification Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)